# Vue-chartjs v4.0.7 instance access (to chart object)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, instance

I'm a newbie javascript dev,

I'm trying to access the size properties of two charts, done with vue-chartjs v4, inside the code - not in the console.
This is easier to find these properties in the console, but the objects inside the console are not accessible from the code (i don't really know why) except some values that are direct relatives to the properties the console.log came from :

```
                duplicatedOptions.scales.x.afterFit = context => {
                    console.log("dup x context", context);
                    context.height += 25;
                };
```

In this block, `duplicatedOptions` is the options variable for the second chart. in this console.log, I do access some properties. Only a few of them are made usable in my code, , the properties that are relative to the x scale, but and not the ones I want.

What I would like is to calculate the `paddingRight` dynamically with these width and sizes for one of the two charts.

In other ways, I would like to acess the hole chart instance and specifically `chart.chartArea.left` made usable in my code..
I'm using vuejs 2.6.14

I tried to put a ref in the chart element as it is recommended in the official documentation. but I can't find my `chartArea.left` variable this time even in the console.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

My teammate found the way to access chart instance with these lines, on vue-chartjs 4.0.7 :

```
const charts = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
        const ctx = charts.getContext("2d");
```

Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

For `vue-chartjs` v5
https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#access-to-chart-instance

For v4

```js
    <line-chart
        ref="wrapper"
        :chartOptions="chartOptions"
    />
```

`this.$refs.wrapper.$data._chart`

Comment: For v5 It returns null.

Comment: Read it again. For vue-chartjs v5 https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#access-to-chart-instance

Comment: That's what I said, for v5 it returns null, tried both options you provided, v5 and v4, just in case, both returns null.